# How to add extra column in AspNetUsersRoles?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I created a model *Restaurant* and added there **Id, Name, Image and AdminId**. Then create a table using **add-migration** parameter. And now I have to add a column **RestaurantId** in AspNetUsersRoles. I've tried to add it manually, but it doesn't work. How can I add extra column in this table and connect it with **Restaurants** table?

Comment: "but it doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything. Thw qhole identity system is fully templated with type params so it should be possible.

Comment: You might find it diifficult to actually use that RestaurantId, you'd have to extend and alter just about everything. It might make more sense to model this with claims.

Comment: @Gulzhanat will you include your code? We need to see how you added this property to the model.

Answer (score 1):

you need to define your model for Role.

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, MyRole>()

public class MyRole : IdentityRole
{
    public int RestaurantId { get; set; }
}
```